# Gmail marks mail as SPAM

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam, swiftmailer

i'm having a big headache with this problem and I don't see any clue on how to fix it.
I have a website that sends

1) Confirmation of Order and

2) The ticket itself after the payment.

It is being sent by Swift Mailer and here is the thing : The email

1) is being received correctly and the

2) is being marked as spam (on Gmail).

What is the logic in this? I mean they both have attachments and the headers are pretty similar (see below):

**1 - OK**

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.84.39 with SMTP id k36csp20891qgd;
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:12:29 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.49.117.133 with SMTP id ke5mr20030949qeb.53.1385118749265;
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:12:29 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <info@myserver.com.br>
Received: from myserver.com.br ([ServerIP])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id lz7si9980075qcb.55.2013.11.22.03.12.27
        for <multiple recipients>
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:12:29 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@myserver.com.br designates [ServerIP] as permitted sender) client-ip=[ServerIP];
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@myserver.com.br designates [ServerIP] as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@myserver.com.br
Received: by myserver.com.br (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id B8D2B8AA404; Fri, 22 Nov 2013 09:12:20 -0200 (BRST)
To: My GMAIL  <myemail@gmail.com>
Subject: Os seus bilhetes (Encomenda nr. 43)
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:SimpleMailInvoker.php
Message-ID: <1385118738.528f3c1246658@www.myserver.com.br>
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 09:12:18 -0200
From: MyServer <info@myserver.com.br>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1385118738528f3c12491cb_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1385118738528f3c12491cb_=_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1385118740528f3c1487bab_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1385118740528f3c1487bab_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=20
(TEXT-HERE)


--_=_swift_v4_1385118740528f3c1487bab_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

(TEXT-HERE)

--_=_swift_v4_1385118740528f3c1487bab_=_--


--_=_swift_v4_1385118738528f3c12491cb_=_
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=order_43_Bilhetes.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order_43_Bilhetes.pdf

(PDF-CONTENT-HERE)

--_=_swift_v4_1385118738528f3c12491cb_=_--
```

**2 - SPAMMY**

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.84.39 with SMTP id k36csp20836qgd;
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:11:22 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.224.24.201 with SMTP id w9mr2626825qab.103.1385118682006;
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:11:22 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <info@myserver.com.br>
Received: from myserver.com.br ([[ServerIP]])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id kb1si10321504qeb.37.2013.11.22.03.11.21
        for <myemail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 22 Nov 2013 03:11:21 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@myserver.com.br designates [ServerIP] as permitted sender) client-ip=[ServerIP];
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@myserver.com.br designates [ServerIP] as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@myserver.com.br
Received: by myserver.com.br (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 37FE58AA404; Fri, 22 Nov 2013 09:11:14 -0200 (BRST)
To: Diogo GMAIL  <myemail@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Confirma=C3=A7=C3=A3o?= da encomenda nr. 42
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:SimpleMailInvoker.php
Message-ID: <1385118671.528f3bcfda2dd@www.myserver.com.br>
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 09:11:11 -0200
From: myserver <info@myserver.com.br>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1385118671528f3bcfdc6a3_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1385118671528f3bcfdc6a3_=_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1385118674528f3bd21c29f_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1385118674528f3bd21c29f_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

(TEXT-HERE)

--_=_swift_v4_1385118674528f3bd21c29f_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

(TEXT-HERE)

--_=_swift_v4_1385118674528f3bd21c29f_=_--


--_=_swift_v4_1385118671528f3bcfdc6a3_=_
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=order_42_Multibanco.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order_42_Multibanco.pdf

(PDF-CONTENT-HERE)
--_=_swift_v4_1385118671528f3bcfdc6a3_=_--
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the key difference between the two is that on one you send to **<multiple recipients>** and on the other you send to an actual email address, ie: **<myemail@gmail.com>** (line 9 is the only thing that jumps out at me as being a different format)?

Comment: Try moving your spammy one closer and closer to the working one, step my step.  First up, you have a UTF-8 encoded subject in the spam one.

Comment: Good spot - the received header states multiple recipients despite only having one "to" address - unfortunately the multiple recipients mail is the one not marked as spam!

Comment: Hmmm I'm going to try to send it only to one recipient. But I wonder if that is somekind of flag to the Gmail to mark it as spam -.-

Comment: Just a random thought, did you send the first one, click 'Not Spam' when it went to the spam inbox, and then send the second one (the OK one was sent a minute and a half later)?

Comment: nop, i have tried on another account and the process is similar. I guess the multiple recipients might be the problem

Comment: Now I send only to one recipient (the <multiple reciepients> don't show anymore), but it still gets to spam! Damn

Comment: It was an <a href="" in the link description. Seems to be a flag to warn google that it is spam -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the content. Using large money figures, certain words like 'free' and exclamation points (!), are all considered spammy. It is an accumulative score, so although these things are okay to use, if you have them all in your email, it can tip you over the limit.

Try sending the email with the content stripped out to rule out the possibility of content causing the issue.

Comment: it really seems that way... I totally replace my subject and content to some other text and it gone right through the inbox :)

Comment: If it is something you frequently have issues with, I suggest getting [Litmus](https://litmus.com/spam-filter-tests), they have really good spam testing built in, that tells you what and why things are getting flagged in each email client/spam blocking software.

Comment: I had a link in the description. So I removed the <a href=... and all seems ok. Can't I have links in the description? Weird :(